# Vscode indent guide: how can I lessen (not hide) vertical lines that is too many / aggresive?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, themes, indentation

[image]

I am new to vscode, how can I get only one vertical line for each indented block, or... just mask it less ugly... like this...

[image]

Comment: they are the tab stops, not indent guides, the indent guide is only one showing the inner most grouping that the cursor is in. See if there is a color setting for the tab stops and change it in the settings for this theme

Comment: Hi @rioV8, I searched for 'tab stop', and there is only one found 'Editor: Use Tab Stops
Inserting and deleting whitespace follows tab stops.' I try to cancel it but it doesn't make any changes even editor reopened.

Comment: don't search the settings but the theme colors, and then change the color in the settings, probably you want to change the transparency of the color. If I change the Theme the color of tab stops changes so it is a theme color

Comment: I found TabStops is jumping through arguments of snippet. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops)

Comment: And those vertical lines what we are talking about is `IndentGuide`, but thanks to your comment, I found a solution in doc of themecolors (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a perfect solution, but

[image]

According to [vscode doc of ThemeColor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color),
there is

- `editorIndentGuide.background`: Color of the editor indentation guides.
- `editorIndentGuide.activeBackground`: Color of the active editor indentation guide.

So I set `editorIndentGuide.background` to the value of `editor.background`

```
{
  ...other thing...
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#F3F3F3",
  }
}
```

So only the non-active indentguides "diappear".